# Goof off or WD 40 to remove paint transfer on car bumper?

Tags: repair, paint, paint-scratches, paint-clearcoat

Some idiot rubbed against my bumper in parking and it appears that there is a paint transfer on my bumper. I have read certain threads on how to remove such transfers. Some people recommend Goof Off, some Wd 40 or acetone etc. I want to get an opinion which would be the best way to remove this transfer with minimum damage to my clear coat and base paint?

FollowUp question: After removing the paint transfer I am planning to do the rubbing with 3M rubbing compound, followed by polishing of the damaged area. Also, need recommendations if I need to apply a clear coat on the damaged area or will a paint sealant also work?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!